# VBA Workaround: Excel XML Export - List of Lists

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on an issue that requires me to generate XML data from an Excel Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, the Export to XML feature within Excel cannot handle List of Lists. I have been unable to find any workarounds outside of outside programs, and am looking for guidance and/or suggestions.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Client>
   <OrderNo></OrderNo>
   <Name></Name>
   <Items>
      <Item ItemCode=""></Item>
      <Item ItemCode=""></Item>
      <Item ItemCode=""></Item>
   </Items>
   <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
</Client>
```

My thought is that I could create a new sheet and have it copy/paste the cell contents into a string. After I'd move the sheet and save it as XML. Would that work?

Comment: I have never tried tricking Excel into outputting Xml that is more complicated than it can handle.  Why not code a bespoke export routine in excel VBA?

Comment: the built in XML tool sucks.. You may use arrays with split to read XML, the join to rebuild it

Comment: @TonyDallimore I haven't done anything like that previously, but thank you for the suggestion. I'm looking into it.